# Why wouldn’t electrons in a CRT just get attracted to the accelerator anode?

Tags: electrons

I was wondering how the accelerator and focus anode in a CRT don’t attract electrons but they just focus and accelerate it? Why don’t electrons stick to it if they have a high potential?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a more detailed description [here](http://www.tpub.com/neets/book6/21e.htm).

Most of the electrons do hit the low voltage anode in the cathode/grid assembly. Those that shoot through the hole are accelerated and focused as shown. Note that the screen and RHS part of the tube are at the high voltage anode potential.

[Here](http://www.r-type.org/articles/art-004e.htm) is an even more detailed  description, but still sort of hand-wavy.